# After installing Ubuntu 20.04 lts my harddisk is not able to boot

Tags: boot

I have a Fujitsu laptop
I tried installing Ubuntu by clearing everything after installing my lap opens say " pxe-e61: media test failure, check cable "
I tried installing in other hard disc but it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Check your boot sequence in your bios. Seem to be trying to network boot and maybe other options are disabled.